# How to make ls command not show Icon? files?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app, ls

I have a folder (say, Downloads) with a custom icon.
When I execute `cd Downloads` and then `ls`, it displays

> Icon?
>   Subfolder1
>   Subfolder2

How can I make the ls command skip (thus not showing) the icon files?
Maybe a .bash_profile function that overrides ls or something like that?

Thank you!

(PS: I'm on OS X 10.8)

Answer (score 5):

OS X's ls doesn't have the --ignore option, but you can install the GNU ls with `brew install coreutils`.

```
alias ls="gls --ignore $'Icon\r'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alias to ls like this:

```
alias ls='ls --ignore=Icon*'
```